# A query to return a mix of SUM and COUNT in 5 joined tables

Tags: sql

I have a table named Ads, containing one row for each ad.

| ID | AdTitle | AdDescription | ... |

I also have 3 tables named Applications, Referrals and Subscribers, with rows for each application, referral and subscriber associated with an Ad.

| ID | AdID | ApplicantName | ApplicantEmail | ... |

| ID | AdID | ReferrerEmail | ReferralEmail | ... |

| ID | AdID | SubscriberEmail | ... |

Finally I have a table named Views with one row for each ad, containing the total number of views for that ad.

| ID | AdID | Views |

I'm trying to write a query with a summary for each ad in 6 columns: Ad ID, Ad title, number of applications/referrals/subscribers and total views.

A simple query of all tables that I have been working with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ads
LEFT JOIN Applications ON Ads.ID = Applications.AdID
LEFT JOIN Referrals ON Ads.ID = Referrals.AdID
LEFT JOIN Subscribers ON Ads.ID = Subscribers.AdID
LEFT JOIN Views ON Ads.ID = Views.AdID
```

I have tried a lot of combinations of LEFT and INNER joins, GROUP BY, COUNT(...), COUNT(DISTINCT ...) and SUM(CASE ...) but nothing so far have worked. I end up counting NULL values from previous columns, counting entries twice or not at all, counting the number of rows in the Views-table instead of adding them together and so on.

Is it better to split this up in multiple querys, or is there a good way to archive what I want with a single one?

Comment: What is your expected results? Just the count of referral, applicant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *,
(select count (*) from Applications as A1 where A.ID = A1.AdID ) as Applicants,
(select count(*) from Referrals as R where A.ID = R.AdID ) as Referrals,
(select count(*) from Subscribers as S where A.ID = S.AdID ) as Subscribers,
(select count(*) from Views  as V where A.ID = V.AdID ) as Views
FROM Ads as A
```

Comment: Works great with some modifications! As described in my question, the Views table didn't have a row for each "view", but a single row per ad with total number of views. Was an easy fix. Thanks!